# PHP - SQL query with MAX() returns null

Tags: sql, max

I'm trying to retrieve a record that already inserted to the database. I do this by using `MAX(id)` but it would always return `null`. I've tried to running the query in `phpmyadmin` and it works. I've tried other methods I've found in the site but none of them work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblgroups (cid, name) values(?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array("1", $name));

    $sql = "SELECT MAX(gid) AS gid FROM tblgroups";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $gid = $data['gid'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblcategories (cid, gid, name, text_color, bg_color) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array("1", $gid, $name, "#FF0000", "#FFFFFF"));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblusers (username, password, gid) values(?, ?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name, md5("password"), $gid));


    $sql = "SELECT MAX(uid) AS uid FROM tblusers";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $uid = $data['uid'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbluser_groups (gid, uid) values(?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($gid, $uid));
```

Comment: you are inserting `cid` and fetching `gid` is it right ?

Comment: Can you post your schemas? Make sure the columns you are selecting are actually auto_increment.

Comment: Both gid and uid are on auto increment.

Comment: cid refers to another table which will always have just 1 entry so cid will always be "1". Here is a schema I quickly drew.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzL0TPHrAftmMnYxN3JQNm1MNzlJMDlseU9seHVycnhHLVEw/view?usp=sharing